# Pre- calculus and calculus practice questions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I'll be taking pre-calculus this fall, and I am wondering if anyone on here can recommend a good problem solving workbook with lots of questions for practice.Also,any ideas for calculus I and calculus II are welcomed too.Thank You

Comment: The Schaum's Outline series has plenty of examples and problems (and are cheap) for all three topics.

Comment: Thank You for the recommendation.I'll definitely check them out.

Answer (score 2):

You can register to [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) for free. There are many practice problems and video lectures. There are also exam prep questions. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are many good books but perhaps the best to try are the following:

1. Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell by George. F. Simmons
2. The Complete Idiots Guide to Precalculus
3. Precalculus. by Carl Stitz (try it)
4. Modern Calculus by Ra Silverman (good book)
5. Problem Solving Strategies is a nice book

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Algebra, Functions and Graphs, Trigonometry, and The Method of Coordinates by I. M. Gelfand is a good book take to take a look at.